# readjust Horizontal menu to resolution

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this, so I'm clueless.

Whenever I go to my site with a different resolution the menu changes a lot and does not align correctly. Just tell me if i need more of the html or css.
My webpage is [Aulan.co](http://aulan.co)

**My code:**

```css
ul {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    line-height: 150%;
    margin-left: 3em;
    margin-right: 5em;
}
  
#menu {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: auto;
      width: 90%;
      height: auto;
      padding: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #353B4E;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

li {
    text-align: center;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 70px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: auto;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    display: inline;
}

#menus {
float: left;
```

```html
<h1> AuLan </h1>
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="menus"><a class="active">Forside</a></li>
  <li id="menus"><a href="info.html">Informasjon</a></li>
  <li id="menus"><a href="regler.html">Regler</a></li>
  <li id="menus"><a href="crew.html">Crew</a></li>
  <li id="menus"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt oss</a></li>
  <li id="menus"><a href="seat.html">Seatmap</a></li>
  <li id="menus"><a href="time.html">Timeplan</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not really clear what you want to achieve, but I tried to change your code in a way that I think you might want. I took out a lot of unneccessary code from the CSS and added some. In the HTML, i change the `menus`ID to a class, since IDs should only be used *once* per page.

You can adjust especially the `min-width` and `padding` setting in the `menu li a` rule to your needs (but also the other width and padding settings)

```css
 
#menu {
      font-size: 25px;
      list-style-type: none;
      width: 90%;
      background-color: #353B4E;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 150%;
}
#menu li a {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100px;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<h1> AuLan </h1>
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="menus"><a class="active">Forside</a></li>
  <li class="menus"><a href="info.html">Informasjon</a></li>
  <li class="menus"><a href="regler.html">Regler</a></li>
  <li class="menus"><a href="crew.html">Crew</a></li>
  <li class="menus"><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt oss</a></li>
  <li class="menus"><a href="seat.html">Seatmap</a></li>
  <li class="menus"><a href="time.html">Timeplan</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks alot really appreciate it!